# How to not reload "getView" of ListView adapter when I drag the list view Up & Down?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

To follow the question in the subject, how can I make sure the row won't get loaded again when there is invalidate on the screen ?

I just want the screen and the list view to stay as is when the user drag it up and down.

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it is not possible. For this purpose you should use a `ScrollView`

Comment: But can i use custom adapter in scrollview like i did in my custom list view?